# 2 identical Controls in the same Grid ? (WPF/xaml)

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is a simple code that exposes my problem :

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView Name="myTreeViewEvent" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="Employee1"/>
    </TreeView>
    <TreeView Name="myTreeViewEvent2" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="Employee2"/>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

The thing is that my 2nd Treeview "overwrites" the 1st one...
Is there a way to change the behaviour so that the 2nd Treeview is "added" to the 1st one ?

(nb : no, I can't put them in the same Treeview cause in my "real" code, I got 2 different Treeviews that I CAN'T merge... and I gotta display them in the same grid !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TreeView Name="myTreeViewEvent" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="Employee1"/>
    </TreeView>
    <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Name="myTreeViewEvent2" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="Employee2"/>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT**
Then what prevents you from using this approach?

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>    
            <TreeView Name="myTreeViewEvent">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Employee1"/>
            </TreeView>
            <TreeView Name="myTreeViewEvent2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Employee2"/>
            </TreeView>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In this case there is no strict division. The items will strech up.

Comment: The thing is that my whole grid is already divided in rows/columns ! And I want my 2 Treeviews in the same area (ie. row/column)
I don't wanna split my area in 2 zones cause sometimes one of my 2 Treeview will be empty !

Comment: I have modified answer slightly

Comment: Works like a charm !
Just a detail, is there a way to hide the separations in the StackPanel ? at the moment I can see a line between my 2 Treeviews and I'd like to remove this separation/line !

Comment: StackPanel has no default styling. No lines and backgrounds. Most probably if there is a line you need to look at your treeviews. I never worked with treeview but you need to check out for its styling rules. Cheers.

Comment: That's strange because when I create a single Treeview in a grid, there is no line "framing" my Treeview :o I really feel like every item in the StackPanel is "framed" :/ I did this test :
    <Grid>
            <TreeView Name="myTreeViewEvent">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Employee1"/>
            </TreeView>
    </Grid>
=> The TreeView is NOT framed.....
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TreeView Name="myTreeViewEvent">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Employee1"/>
            </TreeView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
=> The Treeview is framed !!!

Comment: Try margins to treeviews for each your mentioned cases and figure out what control exactly has that line.